# Modify a R code to generate a differenty output

Tags: r

```
set.seed(2019)
numHeads <- t(replicate(1000, sample(1:0, 4, TRUE)))
mean(rowSums(numHeads)
```

I need to modify this code so that we can repeat tossing a fair coin now 10000   until a head is obtained and find an empirical average of this experiment.

Comment: First off: I strongly recommend that you run the code bit-by-bit: start with the `sample(...)` command and then work your way up (out). Secondly, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "*repeat tossing a fair coin now 10000 until a head is obtained*". You can *either* toss a coin 10^5 times, *or* you can toss a coin until a head is obtained, *or* you can toss a coin until you get 10^5 heads. Which one is it?

Comment: I meant doing tossing the coin 10000 and count how many heads you get on average

Comment: Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On average it's 1.9 flips until a heads comes up.  The key is the while statement which runs until a condition is true (in this case you get something other than 0).  The object "Count" is just how many times the while loop had to run for a 1 to be selected.

```
out <- NULL
for( i in 1:10000){

    count<-0
    a <- 0

    while( a == 0 ){

        set.seed(count+i)
        a <- sample( c(0,1) ,1  )
        count <- count+1

    }

    out <- rbind( out , data.frame( i, count))
}

mean( out$count)
```

Comment: No no no, please don't do this. This is a very un-R-like way of approaching the problem as it completely lacks vectorisation, dynamically grows a `data.frame` which is the most inefficient way of dealing with objects in R, and ignores the fundamental statistical concept that throwing a single die 10000 times (not efficient) is the same as rolling 10000 dice only once (much more efficient).

Comment: According to OP: *"I meant doing tossing the coin 10000 and count how many heads you get on average" "* This doesn't seem to do what OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorised way to repeatedly (`Nrepeat = 100`) toss a coin `Ntoss = 10^5` times.

```
Ntoss <- 10000
Nrepeat <- 100
set.seed(2018)
lst <- replicate(Nrepeat, sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), Ntoss, replace = T), simplify = F)
```

The output object here is a `list` with `10^5` coin toss results per repeated coin toss "experiment".

#### Number of heads amongst the `10^5` coin tosses

To calculate the number of heads amongst the `10^5` coin tosses you can do

```
nHeads <- sapply(lst, sum)
```

#### Fraction of heads amongst the `10^5` coin tosses

To calculate the fraction of heads amongst the `10^5` coin tosses you can do

```
fracHeads <- sapply(lst, function(x) sum(x) / length(x))
# [1] 0.5071 0.5027 0.5033 0.4969 0.5010 0.5010 0.5053 0.4994 0.5027 0.4974
#[11] 0.4937 0.5012 0.5018 0.5006 0.5066 0.4986 0.4987 0.5030 0.4990 0.5050
#[21] 0.4889 0.4986 0.5040 0.4933 0.5002 0.4912 0.4966 0.5046 0.4942 0.5029
#[31] 0.4908 0.5014 0.5002 0.5061 0.5013 0.5051 0.4977 0.4957 0.4990 0.5054
#[41] 0.5086 0.4994 0.4910 0.5032 0.4961 0.4928 0.5108 0.5018 0.5040 0.4973
#[51] 0.5001 0.4989 0.5069 0.5004 0.4946 0.4980 0.4970 0.4988 0.4945 0.4972
#[61] 0.5106 0.5016 0.4932 0.4989 0.4983 0.4969 0.4938 0.5063 0.4962 0.5073
#[71] 0.5020 0.4904 0.4990 0.5025 0.4990 0.4949 0.5009 0.4986 0.4959 0.4886
#[81] 0.4972 0.5055 0.5046 0.5059 0.4980 0.4993 0.4975 0.4959 0.4943 0.5077
#[91] 0.5021 0.5023 0.4977 0.5034 0.4943 0.5056 0.5019 0.5051 0.4980 0.5031
```

#### Distribution of the fraction of heads

We can also plot the distribution of the fraction of heads from the 100 repeated experiments

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(fracHeads = fracHeads), aes(fracHeads)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.  He was asking for the number of flips until a heads is obtained not a proportion.

Comment: @MatthewR *"I meant doing tossing the coin 10000 and count how many heads you get on average"* To me that doesn't read like how you interpreted OP's question. But even *if* your interpretation is correct, your implementation is really just bad R code. I'm happy to remove my downvote if you rewrite your solution; at the moment your solution promotes very poor R coding style. Did you read my comments to your post? Your making some of the *most cardinal mistakes* in R coding (growing objects dynamically, `sample(..., size = 1, ...)` in a loop instead of `sample(...., size = 10^5, ...)`.

Comment: @MatthewR On top of that, if you review my answer carefully `lst` contains the number of heads per `10^5` throws.